# How to make characters line up in front of a kiosk at Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

In my project I have a queue struct which contains character models. I need to make them line up. When the first model on the line leaves it, the one behind it must take his place and all the line also should align again. Any idea for the algorithm? Thanks in advance.

Comment: actually i'm looking for a hint to how can i do that because i'm new at unity i made lots of research but couldn't find anything helpful so if you could give me a idea or show me a resource i would be so happy.

Comment: Will your number of characters change dynamically? Is the line alignment everything in your scenario?

Comment: Characters will spawn at certain times and go to kiosk for queue and after they are done with kiosk they will leave the queue and the one behind will stay a certain time at the front of the queue.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about where exactly you problem is with implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to make the kiosk manage its queue. To do this, your kiosk game object should have some information about the queue, at the bare minimum it will probably need a normalized vector indicting the direction of the queue away from the kiosk and a linked-list-like structure referring to the other game objects in the queue. You'll probably also want methods on the kiosk to allow other objects to enter and exit the queue.

```
class Kiosk : ... {
  Vector3 queueDirection;
  LinkedListOf<GameObject> queueMembers;

  void RequestEnterQueue(GameObject object);
  void RequestLeaveQueue(GameObject object);
}
```

To enter the queue, a game object calls `RequestEnterQueue` on the kiosk. `RequestEnterQueue` should compute the desired position for the querying game object to walk to in order for it to line up at the back of the queue. A simple way to do this is to start at the kiosk's position, and displace that position along the queue direction by the kiosk's collision radius. This gives you the idealized location of the first queue position. Continue to displace this position by the collision *diameter* of every object currently in the member list. This gives you the idealized location of of new game object's position in the queue. Displace this position by the new game object's collision radius to get the actual center point the game object should walk to. Tell the game object to walk to that position, and put the game object on the end of the queue list.

To exit the queue, a game object would call `RequestLeaveQueue`. This removes the game object from the member queue list and tells it to move somewhere else. Then, for every member object still in the queue, tell that object to move forward along the opposite of the queue direction by the collision radius of the game object that left the queue.

---

This process is simple to implement. It has the advantage of centrally coordinating the queue management, which means it's easier to do operations on the entire queue. For example, the kiosk can easily tell the first member of the queue to do something (whatever the kiosk is for, withdraw money from a bank account or add a hamburger to the game object's inventory, et cetera), can easily tell every member of the queue to play a bored fidget animation at various times, et cetera.

The disadvantage is that the game object's don't naturally know that they are in the queue unless you add some state to them to indicate that fact. This means they could easily "fight" with the kiosk (the kiosk says "line up here," but something else, maybe even another kiosk the object is trying to line up with, says "no, line up there" and the object jitters back and forth like it can't make up its mind).

Depending on the complexity of other potential interactions with those game objects in the world, this might not be an ideal approach to structuring the queue management (although the approach for actually forming the line could be translated relatively easily to any other way you want to represent the fact that an object is "in the queue").

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to get characters to **Physically** line up, then I would say you could try to have the kiosk keep track of position values that correspond to a queue position, then the characters could automatically travel to queue positions depending on where they are in the queue itself.